# 403 Forbidden for Drive requests in Google Apps Marketplace App

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-drive-api

Using a Google Apps Marketplace App installed from the Chrome Web Store with a full Drive scope works fine except when I unchecked the  "Allow users to install Google Drive Apps" in Drive settings then I get this error with all Drive interactions:

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
This makes sense but reading this [announcement](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/05/domain-management-of-google-drive-apps.html) I thought installing the App would be white listed:

"With today’s launch, Marketplace applications deployed by admins will be able to integrate with Google Drive for users who are provided with the app, even if this Admin Console setting is disabled. In essence, admins can now whitelist the Drive applications that their users can install."

Comment: I don't fully understand, is it an app from marketplace? or from chrome web store? this is the link for the chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps and to get to the market place (the new version)  in  Admin Console in the right panel there is a section called Tools there you can find the access to marketplace.

Comment: Sorry, Google Apps Marketplace only, the link still makes reference to chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/general-audit-tool-+-emai/lfbajpekgkppdkandiplblkcfinngjmh.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this problem; the authorization works correctly even when Drive Apps are disabled for the domain. Can you test this again and see if it's still an issue?

Comment: I forgot to mention the scope we are using is "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" because it is an old app migrated to the new apps marketplace. I can reproduce it always.